# Converting Chromewebdriver to Edgewebdriver

Tags: python, web-scraping, microsoft-edge

I have written a code that will run selenium using chromewebdriver. now i need to convert the code so that it will run msedgedriver. can someone send the code which is converted so that it will run on msedge driver and tell me how did they do it so that i can write the code the same way in future.

here is my code:

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



'''locators'''
bank_cost_lt=(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='itembox-InstantBankDiscount']//a")
x_mark_lt=(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='twister-plus-dp-bg']/i")
partner_lt=(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='itembox-Partner']//a[@class='a-size-base a-link-emphasis vsx-offers-count']")


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
# driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_exe_path, chrome_options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), chrome_options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
# driver.maximize_window()

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['url','price','seller','bank offers','partner offers'])
cnt=0

def presence_of_element_click(by_locator, timeout):
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(by_locator)).click()

urls=["https://www.amazon.in/JBL-Cancellation-Headphones-Playtime-Assistant/dp/B096FYLJ6M/ref=sr_1_8?crid=OHZVHJG9Q7HN&keywords=jbl%2Bheadphones&qid=1672115942&s=electronics&sprefix=jbl%2Bheadphone%2Celectronics%2C235&sr=1-8&th=1"]

# urls = ["https://www.amazon.in/dp/B0BGZN7FWV?th=1"]
for url in urls:
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 180).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
    elem = driver.find_element('xpath','//*')
    source_code = elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")
    price = soup2.find('span',{'class':'a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay'}).span.text
    print(price)
    seller=soup2.find('div',{'id':'merchant-info'}).find('a').find('span').text
    print(seller)
    presence_of_element_click(bank_cost_lt,60)
    time.sleep(4)
    bank_=driver.find_element('id','InstantBankDiscount-sideSheet')
    source_code = bank_.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")
    bank_offer_els=soup2.find_all('div',{'class':'a-section vsx-offers-desktop-lv__item'})
    lst=[]
    for val in bank_offer_els:
        lst.append(str(val.p.text).strip())
    presence_of_element_click(x_mark_lt,60)
    time.sleep(2)
    presence_of_element_click(partner_lt,60)
    time.sleep(2)
    bank_=driver.find_element('id','Partner-single-offer')
    source_code = bank_.get_attribute("outerHTML")
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "html.parser")
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(soup1.prettify(), "html.parser")
    partner_els=soup2.find_all('div',{'class':'a-section vsx-offers-desktop-dv__content aok-block'})
    par_lst=[]
    for val in partner_els:
        par_lst.append(str(val.text).strip())
    presence_of_element_click(x_mark_lt,60)
    df.loc[cnt,'url']=url
    df.loc[cnt,'price']=price.strip()
    df.loc[cnt,'seller']= seller.strip()
    if lst:
        df.loc[cnt,'bank offers']=', '.join(lst)
    else:
        df.loc[cnt,'bank offers']='No offers'
    if par_lst:
        df.loc[cnt,'partner offers']=', '.join(par_lst)
    else:
        df.loc[cnt,'partner offers']='No Offers'
    cnt+=1
df.to_excel('output1.xlsx',index=False)
```

Comment: May I know if you have got any chance to check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75134560/converting-chromewebdriver-to-edgewebdriver/75142397#75142397) below? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Selenium 4, you only need to change Chrome related code to Edge related. The edited lines of code are below:

```
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()), options=options)
```

If you want to learn more about Edge WebDriver automation, you can refer to this doc: [Use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python).